# Magento 2 .gitignore template in combination with Deploybot and Git workflow

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, git, deployment

I installed Magento 2 using composer locally (on my local Dev environment using MAMP).

- I added my custom theme and did all my frontend work on my local Dev site.
- I want my code and changes to be tracked by Git and pull it in on my
  Staging site (from the Beanstalk remote repo)

I installed Magento 2 using Composer and @Claudiu Creanga advised me in [this article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117888/magento-2-deployment-from-dev-to-staging-using-git) to use the service Deploybot to deploy the site to Staging.

I have a few questions regarding this process:

1. How do I have to setup my .gitignore file? In other words; which
   files and folders I have to track and I have to commit and push to
   my remote repo?
2. How do I install my site on the Staging server? Also using Composer?
3. Because I used Composer to install Magento 2, I can use `composer
   update` to update Magento 2 core. But how do I update my Staging
   site? Also using `composer update`? So if I understand wright I
   don't pull in this update changes by Git from my remote repo?
4. How do I install and update Extensions? Also using Composer? So I
   don't add the Extensions via Git and I don't track the Extensions,
   isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this [.gitignore](https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/blob/master/.gitignore)

In my opinion you should remove the line `/dev/tools/grunt` as you want to track the grunt folder. You deploy the composer files and a few other folders needed.

Then on your staging server you run automatic commands like:

```
cd ~/your_root_folder
php bin/magento cache:flush
composer install
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
grunt clean
grunt exec
grunt less
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
```

Depending on your configuration other commands may need to run.

Ideally you should install extensions with composer because it makes managing dependencies better. The truth is that few vendors offer them through composer, they still send you a zip package via email. So you should drop it in the app/code folder which is tracked by git.

*If you're using mamp, check the php version. Magento2 doesn't work with php 7.0.0 and mamp didn't yet release a newer version of php7 I think.

Comment: Thanks! About the `.gitignore` file; I added your `.gitignore` but it still tracking 32169 files? **1)** Do I have to add `/node_modules` and what about `/update` folder? Do I have to add `/update` also to `.gitignore` file?  **2)** What is the purpose of tracking the grunt folder? **3)** To get things clear: What are my steps to get my Staging server ready? I am a bit lost here? Do I have to do a `composer install` on my Staging server. What steps I have to do to migrate my local version to staging server using composer and Deploybot etc?

Comment: /node_modules should not be tracked so add it to your .gitignore. track the grunt folder because in themes.js you will add your theme settings. yes, you need to do a composer install on the staging server. composer update locally, push to staging  and on staging composer installl

Comment: **1)** So I will track the _whole_ `/dev/tools/grunt` folder in Git? And what about the `/update folder`? **2)** So after I properly set my `.gitignore` I push all tracked code to Beanstalk remote repo. Till here I can follow the proces. But what do I have to do next? Where does Deploybot is getting involved. And before hand what do I have to do on the Staging server? **3)** Can you explain this 'composer update locally, push to staging and on staging composer installl'. I don't understand exactly the proces?

Comment: sorry but do you have an answer on my last comment? Thanks!!

Comment: In addition: **1)** For what do I need Composer anyway on Staging server? Is this to get the vendors once only on the Staging server? Why shouldn't I do this via ssh on the server with `php composer.phar install` ? **2)**  I need Composer on the Staging server only 1 time for the installation isn't it? The site isn't getting 100 visitors per hour and are symlinks working on shared hosting?

Comment: Why should `/dev/tests/` be ignored? These are your test configurations.